# Run php exec function to stop windows services

Tags: php, printing, windows-services, uac, administrator

I have written a web program in php that needs to stop a windows service and start's it when run like this:

```
 exec('net stop spooler'); //to stop printer spooler
 exec('net start spooler'); //to start printer spooler
```

the above codes doesnt stop the printer spooler and i think i know why, because when i open up cmd- command prompt normally and type `net start spooler` i get access deny...but when i open cmd - command prompt as administrator the command line will work, so i think apache also needs to be given administrator permission so that the above code can work but i cant figure out how to grant the code to run as administrator.

the printer spooler windows service can be found when you click start > type run> in run command type services.msc then you will see printer spooler as one of the windows services...when the above code runs...it should stop that service or starts it

Comment: Your diagnosis sounds spot on and introducing the correct credentials should resolve the problem. This might be better resolved on ServerFault.com as it relates to platform security rather than programming.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your apache setup, you may need to set apache to run as administrator

1. Go to Control Panel->Administrative Tools_>Services
2. Select the Apache service and hit Properties
3. On the Log On tab try to change it to administrator
4. Restart Apache

But generally it might not necessarily be the best idea to run apache with such high authority.